# Apache Drill | How to configure Spill on disk

Tags: memory-management, filesystems, hdfs, apache-drill

I doing R&D on Apache drill by querying on 20 million data on 8GB RAM with MySQL and Mongo data source and getting out of memory exception.

Then,tried to configure Spill on disk by following configuration in drill-override.conf.

```
drill.exec: {
 cluster-id: "APDCluster1",
 zk.connect: "192.168.1.16:2181",
 spill: {
  directories: ["/data/enliven/installations/ApacheD/drill/spill"],
  fs: "file:///"
 }
 sort: {
  external: {
   batch.size: 4000,
   spill: {
    batch.size: 4000,
    group.size: 100,
    threshold: 200,
    directories: ["/data/enliven/installations/ApacheD/drill/spill"],
    fs: "file:///"
   }
  }
 },
 hashagg: {
  spill: {
   directories: ["/data/enliven/installations/ApacheD/drill/spill"],
   fs: "file:///"
  }
 }
}
```

Still am getting same out of memory exception .

Any one can help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

The drill-override.conf settings you have is correct (though no need to specify the operator specific settings. The drill.exec.spill.* is common to all spilling operators. The operator specific ones (like drill.exec.hashagg.spill.fs) would be deprecated in the future).

The `planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node` is an important setting. Ideally should be set to a size close to the size of the direct memory, divided by the number of concurrent query streams used. The default setting is 2GB, which is often too small.

Spilling enabled is not a panacea for all memory issues. Need to check the specific detail (examine the stack trace in the log) to find out which operator failed. Some possibilities:

1. Hash Join does not yet support spilling. If need to join a large data set, better disable (`` alter session set `planner.enable_hashjoin` = false; ``) so merge-join will be used instead.
2. The External Sort has a new version ("managed") that handles memory better. To enable using the managed version instead set the configuration of "drill.exec.sort.external.disable_managed" to false. (This would become the default setting in Drill 1.12).
3. The Hash Aggregate spill support is a new feature (Drill 1.12 may work better). Options here: Either disable (`` alter session set `planner.enable_hashagg` = false; ``), or try and increase  "exec.hashagg.min_batches_per_partition" to a higher value (4 or 5).
4. The TopN operator (used when the query has both ORDER BY and LIMIT clauses) had some memory issues (fixed in 1.12). This can be fixed by setting in the configuration override of  "purge.threshold : 10" under drill.exec.sort .

Comment: Thanks.Let me check

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.openkb.info/2015/05/drill-workshop-spill.html, to test the effectiveness of a Drill Spill, you should reduce the provided memory amount to e.g. 20 MB:

```
alter session set `planner.memory.max_query_memory_per_node`=20971520;
```

Then test a query and check the file system if the spill is working at all.

Also, it might be wise to check if you provided enough heap in the first place if you have 8 GB available (from https://drill.apache.org/docs/configuring-drill-memory/):

> The drill-env.sh file contains the following options:

```
#export DRILL_HEAP=${DRILL_HEAP:-"4G”}  
#export DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=${DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY:-"8G"}
```

> To customize memory limits, uncomment the line needed and change the setting:

```
export DRILL_HEAP=${DRILL_HEAP:-"<limit>”}
export DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY=${DRILL_MAX_DIRECT_MEMORY:-“<limit>"}
```

Comment: Thanks..let me check